# HAProxy- Howto test regular expressions

Tags: regex, haproxy

Frontend:

`http://foo.com/test/a/b/c -> backend: http://backend01:8080/a/b/c`

I currently trying to test a regular expression for haproxy 1.8.The used syntax within haproxy for regex is different, so where and how can i test the expression online ? I already tried regex101.com but couldn't find a way to test without errors:

For accessing the backend i use:

```
reqrep ^([^\ ]*\ /)test[/]?(.*)     \1\2
```

This works so far and removes /test from the url when accessing the backend.

But what i also need is to change the response from the backend, so the /test/ is added i back before responding to the client :

`http://backend01:8080/a/b/c  -> http://foo.com/test/a/b/c`

i tried:

`rspirep ^Location:\ http://backend01:8080/(.*)   Location:\ https://foo.com/test/`

But this doesn't reflect the complete url.. So how can i test the haproxy regular expression for this ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: `rspirep ^Location:\ http://backend01:8080/(.*)   Location:\ https://foo.com/test/\1` does not work?